# How to Organize HTML Templates

Tags: html, templates, local-storage, jquery-templates, ejs

I'm wanting to use a bunch of client-side EJS (or jQuery) HTML Templates in the browser, and I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions for how to organize them. I definitely don't want to mix them into the JavaScript or HTML, and I don't want to have to make additional AJAX requests just to get them from the server. Once I have them loaded into JS variables, I will cache them using HTML5's local storage. Thoughts anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I either load them as JSON object `$.getJSON()` with ajax call or simply write them in hidden text area divs inside html

```
<textarea id="template1" style="display:none">
   // here be template code
</textarea>
```

Most HTML editors tolerate this without messing up the syntax checking.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to load them with $.getJSON because it's another request that has to get made and rendering can't begin until that's back. Inside a <div> or <textarea> is probably the best option. Ideally there's something similar to jQuery templates which pull in files with <script type="text/template"> type thing.

Comment: If you use textarea note that you need to unescape the HTML before using them. Check this for pretty easy template solution: http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/JavaScriptTemplates